# how to use NULLIF with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, nullif

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012. I'm getting a 'Divide by zero error encountered' error.  I'm aware this requires the use of NULLIF but I'm unsure how to use it in my query.

This is my query

```
select 
    Ward,
    LocalAuthority,
    Fiscal,
    DR,

    cast(DR*100.0 /SUM(DR) OVER (
        partition by localauthority, fiscal
        order by fiscal asc) as Decimal (10,2)) as [DR%]
from (
    select  
        Fiscal,
        LocalAuthority,
        Ward,
        sum(case when code = 'DR' then 1 else 0 end) as DR
    from [dbo].[Table]
    where datetimeofcall >= '2014-04-01' 
    group by
        ward,
        localauthority,f
        fiscal
) as A
```

I've actually asked this question before which some kind person answered excellently but that was without the OVER() and SUM aggregate function, I'm getting in a muddle with the syntax.  I've been trying various connotations of the below without success.

```
cast(DR*100.0 /NULLIF(SUM(DR,0),1) OVER(partition by localauthority,fiscal order by fiscal asc) as Decimal (10,2)) as [DR%]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Case Expression` to identify the 0 in prior

```
SELECT Ward, LocalAuthority, Fiscal, DR,
CASE WHEN SUM(DR) OVER(PARTITION BY localauthority, fiscal ORDER BY fiscal asc) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(DR*100.0 / SUM(DR) OVER(PARTITION BY  localauthority,fiscal ORDER BY fiscal) AS Decimal (10,2)) END AS [DR%]
FROM (
      SELECT Fiscal, LocalAuthority, Ward, SUM(CASE WHEN code = 'DR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DR
      FROM [dbo].[Table]
      WHERE datetimeofcall >='2014-04-01' 
      GROUP BY ward, localauthority, fiscal
     ) AS A
```